# Issue looping through an object and adding to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, hubspot-cms

So I am trying to get some data from an API do some translation on it and return the values.
This is pulling data from hubspot's hubdb API but when the data returns you do not get the field names back so I need to run it through a function to get the field names.
I was able to successfully do this on a single row using the following.

```js
return axios.get('urltoapi').then((res) => {
 const row = res.data;
 return convertHubdbKeyValues(table_name, row.values).then((details) => {
  return {
   details,
  };
 });
});
```

I have then tried to loop through a number of rows to build an array of data but all I get back is an empty array, I'm sure I'm doing something very basic wrong here

```js
return axios
 .get(getRowByQueryUrl(table_details.table_id, query))
 .then((res) => {
  var bookings = [];
  this.data = res.data;
  this.data.objects.forEach((item) => {
   return convertHubdbKeyValues(table_name, item.values).then(
    (updatedValues) => {
     bookings.push(updatedValues);
    }
   );
  });
  return bookings;
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation, the `bookings` array is returned before the asynchronous calls inside the `forEach` are complete. One way to get around this is to use `Promise.all`:

```
return axios
 .get(getRowByQueryUrl(table_details.table_id, query))
 .then((res) => {
  const promises = res.data.objects.map(item => convertHubdbKeyValues(table_name, item.values))
  return Promise.all(promises)
 });
```

The top-level function will return a promise that resolves to an array of `updatedValues`, as you call them above.